# Postgresql 6.9.24 on Oracle Linux 8.6

Tags: postgresql, yum, oracle-linux

I'm trying to install Postgresql 9.6.24 on Oracle Linux 8.6 as it contains some bug fixes and other patches that we need.
This concrete version is not present in the Oracle Linux 8 repositories, only up to version 6.9.22 installing it as a module:

```
yum install @postgresql:9.6
```

I tried to install it from RHEL and CentOS repositories, but I find a lot of dependencies issue that, as much as I try to fix manually, the more dependencies appear.

Is there any way to install this certain version on Ol86? Am I missing something about this version?

Comment: Did you mean PostgreSQL 9.6? Anyway, [it is EOL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/index.html). Migrate to more recent version.

Comment: I'm aware it is EOL, but right now for some reasons complex to explain we cannot migrate to a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether you meant 6.9.x or 9.6.x, there's always a way to install any legacy opensource software on recent OS version:

- build and install it into the custom PREFIX.

For software using autotools/gmake building routines (such as PostgreSQL), this may be accomplished as:

- download and untar the distribution tarball
- cwd into the source directory
- (optionally) define CFLAGS/LDFLAGS needed
- `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/<softwarename-version> --any-additional-flags-you-want`
- gmake all install
- (optionally) add any needed dynamic libraries the software just added into dynamic linker search path